# Alternative if nothing is displaying - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code snippet that displays tickets sold on my website. This shows them on the product listings.

It only displays if a ticket has been sold but I would like it to say '0' if none are sold.

```php
//shop page - show tickets sold
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'sold_tickets', 15);

function sold_tickets() {
    global $post;
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lottery_participants_count', true);
    if( !empty( $subtitle ) ) {

        echo __("<span class='sold'>Sold</span>", '');
        echo "<span class='soldtickets'>".$subtitle.'</span>';

    } 
}
```

I presume it is the `if( !empty( $subtitle ) ) {` but not sure how to make it show a default value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```php
function sold_tickets() {
    global $post;
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lottery_participants_count', true);

    echo __("<span class='sold'>Sold</span>", '');
    echo "<span class='soldtickets'>".($subtitle ?: '0')."</span>";
}
```

This is a simplification (using an elvis operator) of the following code which you may understand better:

```php
function sold_tickets() {
    global $post;
    $subtitle = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_lottery_participants_count', true);
    if(!empty($subtitle)){
        echo __("<span class='sold'>Sold</span>", '');
        echo "<span class='soldtickets'>".$subtitle."</span>";
    } else {
        echo __("<span class='sold'>Sold</span>", '');
        echo "<span class='soldtickets'>0</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! In this case you can click the check mark ✔ icon to accept the answer, marking your question as solved.